# Running ASP.NET upgrade wizard

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I installed Visual Studio 2010 but, when asked if I wanted to upgrade my ASP.NET solution to ASP.NET 4 I said "no".  Now I've changed my mind.

Is there any way to manually run the upgrade wizard?

Comment: I had a couple of projects that cause the RC Upgrade Wizard to crash. This left me in a similar position to you, it wasn't too laborious to change the target framework fore each project to ".NET Framework 4" then remove all references to Framework Assemblies then add in the .NET 4 Versions.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a website you can right click it in Solution Explorer and choose "Property Pages" > Select the "Build" tab, and change "Target Framework" to ".NET Framework 4".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to manually trigger the upgrade wizard...I couldn't find it at least.  Luckily though the manual upgrade steps aren't that bad, you can find them here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx?ppud=4